duplicating delegate view qml
I was writing my custom calendar and ran into the following problem. My rectangle is larger than my delegate, and the delegate is partially rendered twice - On the right you can see the dates that belong to the next month. How can I fix this without changing the rectangle size?

import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Rectangle {
id: _calendar
width: (276)
height: (302)
radius: (12)
color: "#1D1D1D"
border { width: (1); color: "#404040" }

Column {
    x: (20)
    y: (16)
    spacing: 0

    ListView {
        id: _calendarView
        width: (236)
        height: (202)
        snapMode: ListView.SnapOneItem
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
        spacing: 1

        model: CalendarModel {
            id: _model
            from: new Date(2024,3,1)
            to: new Date(2024,7,31)
        }

        delegate: MonthGrid {
            id: _monthGrid

            delegate: Label {
                required property var model

                width: 34
                height: 34
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                font.pixelSize: (14)
                font.bold: true
                opacity: model.month === _monthGrid.month ? 1 : 0.5
                color: "#FFFFFF"
                text: model.day
            }
        }
    }
}
}


What do you mean "the delegate is partially rendered twice"?

On the right you can see the dates that belong to the next month

In your picture, those numbers on the right that are partially cut off are not from the next month. They are the 7th day of the week.

you need to add clip:true to your ListView
ListView {
        id: _calendarView
        width: DpiSettings.scaling(236)
        height: DpiSettings.scaling(202)
        spacing: 1
        clip: true
        snapMode: ListView.SnapOneItem
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange

        model: CalendarModel {
            id: _model
            from: new Date(2024,3,1)
            to: new Date(2024,7,31)
        }

        delegate: MonthGrid {
        id: _monthGrid

        delegate: Label {
            required property var model

            width: 34
            height: 34
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            font.pixelSize: (14)
            font.bold: true
            opacity: model.month === _monthGrid.month ? 1 : 0.5
            color: "#FFFFFF"
            text: model.day
        }
    }
}


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
